# Ajax multiple textbox search request

Tags: php, html, ajax

Hello Im trying to get my textboxes to work with a search option in the database via AJAX.

Im not getting it to work on multiple textboxes, only with one.

This is my code, maby you guys can help me getting it to work. That would be great.

**php**

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=records', 'root', 'l3tm31n');
$select = 'SELECT *';
$from = ' FROM overboekingen';

$opts = (isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : FALSE);
$val = (isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : FALSE);

if ($val != null){
  $where = " WHERE boekingsnummer LIKE '".$val."%'";
}
elseif ($val != null){
  $where = " AND huiscode LIKE '".$val."%'";
}
else {

  if (is_array($opts) || $val){
    $where = ' WHERE FALSE';
  else {
    $where = false;
  }

}

$sql = $select . $from . $where;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($results);
echo($json);
```

**html**

```
<ul id="boekingsnummer" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>Boekingsnummer</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="boekingsnummer" size="20" id="boekingsnummer_1">
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions2" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList2"></li>
</ul> 

<ul id="huiscode" class="hide">                                
            <li><label>huiscode</label></li>
            <li><input type="text" name="huiscode" size="20" id="huiscode_1" >
            <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions5" style="display: none;">
            <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList5"></li>
</ul>
```

**ajax**

```
$('#boekingsnummer_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val());        
});

$('#huiscode_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val());        
});

function updateEmployeesText(val){        
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {text: val},
    success: function(records){
        $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
    }        
}); 
}
```

Comment: Could you share us your HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: First of all FALSE is not NULL.

Comment: @naota Sure I have updated the code with HTML and AJAX code that I use. The HTML stands for the 2 textboxes and the AJAX for the javascript part.

Comment: @user3541335, thanks. What error do you have so far?

Comment: @naota Wel basically I dont get any eror, the 2e textbox is using the same sql statement from textbox 1. I cant seem to get them to work separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
I guess you might want to call the JavaScript function and PHP script like this:
JavaScript

```
$('#boekingsnummer_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val(),'boekingsnummer');        
});

$('#huiscode_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val(),'huiscode');        
});

function updateEmployeesText(val,opt){        
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {text: val, filterOpts:opt},
    success: function(records){
        $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
    }        
}); 
}
```

PHP:

```
$opts = (isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : FALSE);
$val = (isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : FALSE);

if (($val != FALSE) && ($opts == "boekingsnummer")){
  $where = " WHERE boekingsnummer LIKE '".$val."%'";
}elseif (($val != FALSE) && ($opts == "huiscode" )){
  $where = " WHERE huiscode LIKE '".$val."%'";
}
```

Comment: Naota: right this seems to be the problem here, so that the second textfield will not be applied

Comment: @user3541335: try to add in your ajax code the type (booking or huiscode) and than depending on this type buld your sql-query

Comment: @Gizzmo and Naota, So I have to change the elseif construction to and 'IF' + 'AND' construction ?

Comment: @user3541335, it depends on what you would like to achieve with SQL.

Comment: @naota Wel I want to get in each textbox another sql statement so differend results from mysql. Each textbox should get its own results from the database when you type something in it :)

Comment: @naota Thank you so much, this fixed the issue for me :) You have been a great help. Would this als work for a calendar input ? So actually a date input like '30-05-2014' ?

Comment: @naota Uhm I tryed your advise but it seems its not working. When I enter the date it will not filter. Any ideas ?

Comment: @user3541335, OK. Since this page is long enough, could you make another question about it and let me know? I will post an answer for it.

Comment: Sure thing I made another tread on the following page:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891394/textbox-is-not-working-for-date-input