# Textbox is not working for date input

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code that is working except 1 thing and that is the following:

When I type in the textbox a datepicker shows up, when the date is clicked the date is put in the textbox for example '27-05-2014'. Now this should filter the page with the right AJAX output when using code below. Unfortunately it doesnt. Any help is much apriciated.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#boekingsnummer_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val(),'boekingsnummer');        
});

$('#huiscode_1').keyup(function(){        
    updateEmployeesText($(this).val(),'huiscode');        
});

function updateEmployeesText(val,opt){        
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "submit.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: {text: val, filterOpts:opt},
    success: function(records){
        $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
    }        
}); 
}
```

**PHP:**

```
$opts = (isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : FALSE);
$val = (isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : FALSE);

if (($val != FALSE) && ($opts == "boekingsnummer")){
  $where = " WHERE boekingsnummer LIKE '".$val."%'";
}elseif (($val != FALSE) && ($opts == "huiscode" )){
  $where = " WHERE huiscode LIKE '".$val."%'";
}
```

Comment: What DOES it do? Any errors? Which of the two fields is the date? Or are they both? Did you try the query?

Comment: i think you need to click event cause datpicker work like a select not any keyup event will be firing

Comment: "Unfortunately it doesn't" is not how you describe what's happening and *how* something doesn't work.

Comment: try setting the content-type too ---> contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: Could you share us your HTML and JavaScript which shows how datepicker is used?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified which datepicker plugin you using.

Though you have to make ajax call on the update event of datepicker rather on keyup event.

May be that can solve your problem.

Comment: This should be a comment and not a post!

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the content type

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

as far I know, if you dont set this, the server interprets this request as a normal post.

If this doesn't work, show what `echo file_get_contents("php://input")` is printing.

Comment: Could you explain why I need to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254891/what-does-content-type-application-json-charset-utf-8-really-mean the content type is the way the server knows what type of content you are sending.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have all other codes correct in the php file, like out putting the result withn `json_encode()`, try changing the following code:

```
$opts = (isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : FALSE);
$val = (isset($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : FALSE);
```

to:

```
$opts = (isset($_POST['filterOpts'])) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : FALSE;
$val = (isset($_POST['text'])) ? $_POST['text'] : FALSE;
```